# With how many ways can we choose cards?

Tags: combinatorics

With how many ways can we choose, from  usual pack of cards with $52$ cards(that are separated into $4$ colours and $13$ kinds) $5$ cards, $2$ of which should be red($\diamondsuit$ or $\heartsuit$) and $3$ swords?
We don't care about the selection order of the cards.

I thought that it is:
$$\binom{13}{3} \cdot \binom{26}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  Assuming "swords" is the same as spades.

Comment: Great!!!Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I have also an other question. If we wanted to choose $6$ cards(we don't care about the order),from which the three are red($\diamondsuit$ or $\heartsuit$) and the three black and the two of the three red are of the same kind(number),would then the result be: $$\binom{13}{2} \cdot \binom{26}{1}+\binom{26}{3} $$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar, if you have another question, well, ask another question.